# BIRT DataSet Remove duplicates

Tags: duplicates, reporting, birt

I know how to remove duplicates from a table using suppress duplicates or through visibility. Is there a way I can remove duplicates from dataset?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a SQL query to obtain your dataset, then you can change your `SELECT` to  `SELECT DISTINCT`.